# Excel VBA Created Table needing Headers based on specific values found in cells

Tags: excel, vba

I was given prompt, accurate help yesterday.  However I have run into an issue where I now need the code to have dynamic headers.  In the code below, it currently creates a table with the use of a Macro, but as you can see I need to manually type the header names.  How can I have the header names reference cell values?  The table will be different due to different reports, so I need to the table to match the report headers.  I currently have the report headers pasted in a sheet, so I would like to be able to call those values for use as headers when I use this macro.

In addition, I would like the table generated to have the bottom row be a "totals row".  A row that is generating the totals of the numbers in each column.  So for example, the Bottom row of Column A would have the total of all the values in Column A.

````
```
Const COL_CNT = 4 ' cols count of the table (ListObject)
Const COL_KEY = "O" ' used to determine the last row
Const FIRST_ROW = 5
Dim i As Variant
i = InputBox("How many DFSP's in this Supply Chain?", "Enter Quantity")
If Not IsNumeric(i) Then
    MsgBox "Please input a number.", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
If i < 1 Then Exit Sub
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Set sht = Worksheets("Instructions")
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, COL_KEY).End(xlUp).Row
With sht.Cells(LastRow, COL_KEY)
If Len(.Value) > 0 Or (Not .ListObject Is Nothing) Then
    LastRow = LastRow + 1
End If
If LastRow < FIRST_ROW Then LastRow = 5
End With
Dim tabRng As Range
Set tabRng = sht.Cells(LastRow, COL_KEY).Resize(i + 1, COL_CNT)
Dim objTable As ListObject
Set objTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, tabRng, , xlYes)
objTable.HeaderRowRange.Value = Array("Numeric", "Name", "Alpha", "Location")
```
````

Comment: `I need to the table to match the report headers` How does the code know what's the location of header on sheet? Sharing a screenshot is helpful to understand your csae.

Comment: This current code doesnt have that at all, I tried some different things but I could not get it to work. Specifically, the location of the headers the code needs to reference is a Sheet called "Base Data", cells D2 through AS2.

Comment: `The table will be different due to different reports` How to determine what's the right header for the new added table? The code could do it if you provide the logic.

Comment: I currently have a macro that imports the report.  This macro is creating new tables pulling data from that imported data.  The headers from the imported report have the headers I need for the newly created tables that this macro creates.  So the "Base Data" sheet is the lcoatin of the imported data.

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the header from cells D2:AS2 on "Base Data" sheet? That is, there are 42 columns (from D to AS) on new table.

Comment: Exactly.  I already have it creating the 2nd table with the correct columns.  Just dont know how to get the headers to match the headrs on the Base Data sheet.  Also, now that I think about it.  How do I get the table to load in with the Totals row on the bottom?

Comment: Please provide the full detail about the question, otherwise noone know how to answer it. eg. what's the `Totals row`? What's the expected output? Please edit your post to share the detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The header are copied from `HEADER_RNG` on `BASE_SHT` ( modify as needed )
- The quantity of columns on new table is determined by the `HEADER_RNG`.

```vb
Sub Demo()
    Const COL_KEY = "O" ' used to determine the last row
    Const FIRST_ROW = 5
    Const HEADER_RNG = "D2:AS2" ' source of header
    Const BASE_SHT = "Base Data"
    Dim i As Variant
    i = InputBox("How many DFSP's in this Supply Chain?", "Enter Quantity")
    If Not IsNumeric(i) Then
        MsgBox "Please input a number.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If i < 1 Then Exit Sub
    Dim oSht As Worksheet, LastRow As Long
    Set oSht = Worksheets("Instructions")
    LastRow = oSht.Cells(oSht.Rows.Count, COL_KEY).End(xlUp).Row
    With oSht.Cells(LastRow, COL_KEY)
        If Len(.Value) > 0 Or (Not .ListObject Is Nothing) Then
            LastRow = LastRow + 1
        End If
        If LastRow < FIRST_ROW Then LastRow = FIRST_ROW
    End With
    Dim tabRng As Range, headerRng As Range, objTable As ListObject
    set headerRng = Sheets("BASE_SHT").Range(HEADER_RNG)
    Set tabRng = oSht.Cells(LastRow, COL_KEY).Resize(i + 1, headerRng.Columns.Count)
    Set objTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, tabRng, , xlYes)
    objTable.HeaderRowRange.Value = headerRng.Value
End Sub
```